# How to use IFormatProvider in DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, iformatprovider

Why should we use `IFormatProvider` in `DateTime.ParseExact` if there is already a format parameter?

```
DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, format, cultureInfo);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format parameter says what *pattern* to use - but it doesn't say anything about which calendar, month names, short date format etc to use. That's up to the `IFormatProvider`.

For example, suppose you wanted to parse a value with the pattern `"dd MMMM yyyy"` - which month names would you expect to work? If you're using a month name of "February" but you're running on a machine with a system culture of French, it would fail - you'd need to specify an English culture (or the invariant culture) to get it to work. Likewise, you could specify a pattern of `"d"` to mean the short date format - but *which* short date format?

Even the *calendar* you use is affected by the format provider: the value could be parsed into the same year, month and day values in two cultures - but the *meaning* of those values would be very different in a Hijri calendar from a Gregorian calendar, for example.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: It helps that I'm rather interested in dates and times :)

Comment: yes. I know the feeling sometimes.... don't get me started with clients and their requirements and clientside calculation and different regions and.... urgh! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example: [`/`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

`/` is not just a char, but a *date separator* that depends on the culture.